# How to make this code safe from buffer overflow using IF..Statement

Tags: c

```
#include <string.h>

void foo (char *bar)
{
    char  c[12];

    strcpy(c, bar);  // no bounds checking
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    foo(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "How to make this code safe from buffer overflow using IF..Statement", there's no need for an if statement, just use [`strncpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) instead :-)

Comment: Hint you might also want to check an argument is indeed present.

Comment: Note that merely avoiding buffer overflow does not guarantee that your program will actually do the right thing.  Whatever strategy you choose to protect against buffer overflow in any particular circumstance ought to be consistent with the program purpose and specifications.

Comment: `if ( strlen( buf ) >= sizeof c ) { // contents of buf won't fit in c, handle as appropriate } else { strcpy( c, buf ); }`.  This allows you to take some action on overflow - you can either truncate the string as George suggests using `strncpy` (remembering that `strncpy` won't null-terminate the string), or you can return an error, or you can truncate *and* log a warning, etc.

Comment: The data that is coming in should not trusted at all if the security is the issue.  So the appropriate place to check is at the main.  It needs to check for string length of argv[1] and implement appropriate coding according to security related specification.

Answer (score 2):

Another **ACTUAL** option:

```
void foo (char *bar)
{
    char c[12];

    snprintf(c, sizeof c, "%s", bar);
}
```

The functions `strncpy` do not ensure the resulting strings are terminated by a `NULL character` and therefore you can have a `bad resulting string.`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the length of the `bar` is less than `length of c`.

**code:**

```
#include <string.h>

void foo (char *bar)
{
    char  c[12];
    if ( strlen( bar ) < sizeof c ) {
      printf("avoiding buffer overflow");
      strcpy( c, bar );
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    foo(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I made it safe. Otherwise it's doing just the same thing as your original app, that is: nothing.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, the program would have done something if run, and the output depending on whatever `argv[1]` is, is indeterminate as it could invoke UB.

Comment: That "it's doing just the same thing as your original app, that is: nothing." is not correct, the program does do something and there's even a chance for output.

Comment: @George: That's all because of the safety problem. The task was to fix that.